# Typescript, restrict keys to array elements

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

**Edited**: Change ids type

I have an array with the following values

```
const ids: number[] = [45, 56];

const obj: any = {
  45: "HELLO",
  56: "WORLD",
};
```

I would like to type the current `any` type of my object to restrict it to my `ids` array values.

I tried with lookup type but I didn't succeed…

Any idea ?

Regards

Comment: As an aside, the line `const ids: string[] = [45, 56];` is in error; `45` and `56` are not `string`s.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `Record` mapped type. You also need to use a `const` assertion to capture the literal types of the array elements:

```
const ids = [45, 56] as const;

const obj: Record<typeof ids[number], string> = {
    45: "HELLO",
    56: "WORLD",
};
const obj2: Record<typeof ids[number], string> = {
    45: "HELLO",
    56: "WORLD",
    57: "WORLD",  // error
};
```

Comment: Wow! Wonderful, I didn't known that as const existed but it worked, it's used to say that this array is immutable ?

Comment: @ScreamZ yes it makes the array readonly, and as a side effect of this tuples and literal types are preserved (you get `ids` types as `[45, 56]` instead of `number[]`)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create a function that returns a type-checkable object with keys that correspond to array:

```
function indexKeys<K extends string>(keys: readonly K[]) {
  type Result = Record<K, number>;

  const result: Result = {} as Result;

  const {length} = keys;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const k = keys[i];

    result[k] = i;
  }

  return result;
};
```

Here the type-checker will complain:

```ts
// Property 'zz' does not exist on type 'Result'.
const {aa, zz} = indexKeys(['aa', 'bb']);
```